# Tflearn Custom Objective function

Tags: python, tensorflow, tflearn

I am creating a custom objective function for my tflearn model.  The objective function is complex and requires me to iterate through the predicted and correct outputs and add certain parts not based on index.  I cannot find a way to make it work with the tensor datatype.

I have coded a version using standard lists below.

```
errorBuild = 0
errorCheck = 0
def CustomLoss(y_pred, y_true):
    for value, index in enumerate(y_true):
        if y_true[index] == 0:
            errorBuild += y_pred[index]
        else:
            errorBuild += y_pred[index] - y_true[index]
            errorCheck += math.abs(errorBuild)

    return errorCheck
```

There does not seem to be a way to loop through the individual values of a tensor.  Should I be creating a new session in the objective function and evaluating the tensor?

Thanks for the help in advance

Comment: Ideally you would vectorize the loss (maybe involving [cumsum](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/math_ops/scan#cumsum) and tf.abs(y_pred[1:] - y_true)). If that's not possible, I would look at the [TensorFlow looping constructs](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/functional_ops/higher_order_operators).

Answer (score 0):

You can add any new loss function to tflearn/objectives.py file (https://github.com/tflearn/tflearn/blob/master/tflearn/objectives.py). To use it, you just need to call its name in regression layer.

```
def my_own_Loss(y_pred, y_true):
    for value, index in enumerate(y_true):
        if y_true[index] == 0:
            errorBuild += y_pred[index]
        else:
            errorBuild += y_pred[index] - y_true[index]
            errorCheck += math.abs(errorBuild)

    return errorCheck
```

and then call it in:

```
net = tflearn.regression(net, optimizer='momentum',
                         loss='my_own_Loss',
                         learning_rate=0.1)
```